# Xscreensaver Carousel photo randomness vs inclusiveness

Tags: xscreensaver

In xscreensaver I'm using carousel (does same for GLSlideshow...), but notice it only 'randomly' selects very few photo files from the directory for the carousel, many are repeated several times in the carousel, while many never even get chosen, even after many reloads... I'm using dual monitors, and there appears to be two carousels going with differing photo layouts, but still always the same photos get recycled while others always seem to get ignored.

Any way to have it go thru and use all or at least most of the photos in the designated directory? I don't care about randomness, just inclusiveness... I've looked at 'xscreensaver-getimage', but it's not a user level command :-\

Comment: This sounds like this could be ensured with a few lines of, or even less code. Maybe you could open a ticket for it on the project's official bugtracker.

Comment: would not know even how to do that, where to do that, what to convey...

Comment: From [the Ubuntu packages repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xscreensaver) (maybe a preferable resource, as it's Ubuntu-specific?) I found the links to [ask a question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xscreensaver/+addquestion), or to [report a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xscreensaver/+filebug). (Launchpad login needed...)

Comment: Ah look, very detailed instructions on what is expected in a bug report: https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/bugs.html

Comment: Don't think it's a 'bug'... more of a limitation, and SO.....

I emailed the guy in charge of xscreensaver as a 'wish' (ie that randomness be more inclusive). 

A little fyi - I am very limited as to this deep Linux stuff you guys go on about, which is why I post questions here. I have MS nerve damage which has severely impaired my hands (numb + loss of dexterity), so taking notes, running down stuff, is painful and difficult. I'm very old, a cancer surgery chemo survivor, and had VATS w/pleurodsis on both lungs - not long for this world anyway, heh, heh :-}

Comment: Got this back:
Hi Jaimie,

Thanks for sending me your first bug report! Ideally you should file
it in a bug tracker though, and if this was experienced on Ubuntu, you
should file it there first.

Anyway, this is something I have suspected myself sometimes, but I
think it boils down to perception bias. Remember that "random" doesn't
mean all other pictures should be shown before a picture is shown a
second time.

Comment: To investigate this further, which you should do when filing the bug
report, the xscreensaver-image-file command is indeed key. For a
start, just run "xscreensaver-image-file --name ~/Pictures" (or
wherever you have the pictures to be shown) once, then check the
generated cache file ~/.cache/xscreensaver/xscreensaver-getimage.cache
- does it contain all the pictures? If yes, run that command hundreds
of times and see if you get all pictures eventually.

Comment: You could make a
script doing this and adding the selected file names to a log file,
which you can then analyse with "sort", "uniq -c" and so on.

Best regards,
Tormod

Comment: when I do I get:
bash: xscreensaver-image-file --name ~/Pictures: No such file or directory
and:
sudo: /home/batgirl/.cache/xscreensaver/xscreensaver-getimage.cache: command not found

Answer (score 0):

WHOA! Info from Tormod not useful as problem not with 'randomness', and speculation from me that problem was 'not good enough inclusiveness' off base too...

---

The whole problem is apparently **MEMORY**

---

I was advised to change my swapfile size (was 2Gb RAM / 2 GB SWAP) to bigger (2Gb RAM / 4Gb SWAP now) for another issue, and low and behold **ALL** (ie inclusive) the pictures in the directory are now 'randomly' going in and out of the carousel!!!

---

Video memory on the laptop is tied to RAM, and thus to swapfile... my borderline swapfile wasn't robust enough to support the graphically intensive carousel - it took shortcuts :-|